# Powershell script is sending 3 emails instead of 1

Tags: email, powershell

I have a script that pings ip addresses and sends an email if one or more do not succeed. The script is working except, when it sends the email, it sends 3 copies instead of just the one. Any help would be appreciated.

```
param($alert)

# Create the variables
$global:GArgs = $Args
$TimeStop = "23:55"
$errorCount = 0

$urlsToTest = @{}
$urlsToTest["HCC Brandon"] = "ip address"
$urlsToTest["HCC Dale Mabry"] = "ip address"
$urlsToTest["HCC Plant City"] = "ip address"
$urlsToTest["HCC South Shore"] = "ip address"
$urlsToTest["HCC Ybor"] = "ip address"
$urlsToTest["HCC Admin"] = "ip address"

$errorTime =@{}
$errorTime["HCC Brandon"] = "5/7/2015 02:00:00 AM"
$errorTime["HCC Dale Mabry"] = "5/7/2015 02:00:00 AM"
$errorTime["HCC Plant City"] = "5/7/2015 02:00:00 AM"
$errorTime["HCC South Shore"] = "5/7/2015 02:00:00 AM"
$errorTime["HCC Ybor"] = "5/7/2015 02:00:00 AM"
$errorTime["HCC Admin"] = "5/7/2015 02:00:00 AM"

$ping = new-object System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping
Do {
foreach ($key in $urlsToTest.Keys) {
   $output = ""
   $startTime = get-date
   $output = $ping.send($urlsToTest[$key])
   $endTime = get-date

   if (((New-TimeSpan -Start $errorTime[$key]).hours) -ge "1") {
   if ($output.status.tostring() –eq "Success") {
      $key + "`t`tSuccess`t`t" + $startTime.DateTime + "`t`t" + ($endTime - $startTime).TotalSeconds + " seconds"

      if ($GArgs -eq "-log") {
         $key + "`t`tSuccess`t`t" + $startTime.DateTime + "`t`t" + ($endTime - $startTime).TotalSeconds + " seconds" >> BACboneSiteTest.log
      }
   } else {
      $errorCount++
      $key + "`t`tFail`t`t" + $startTime.DateTime + "`t`t" + ($endTime - $startTime).TotalSeconds + " seconds"
      $errorTime[$key] = Get-Date

      if ($GArgs -eq "-log") {
         $key + "`t`tFail`t`t" + $startTime.DateTime + "`t`t" + ($endTime - $startTime).TotalSeconds + " seconds" >> BACboneSiteTest.log
      }
   }
   } else {
   $key + "`t`tSkipping`t`t"
   }
   }
   if ($errorCount -ge 1) {
   if ($alert) {
         $EmailFrom = "emailfrom"
         $EmailTo = "emailto"
         $Subject = "BACbone Test Failure - " + $startTime 
         $body = "BACbone Test Failure: " + $startTime
         $smtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
         $SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587) 
         $SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true 
         $SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
         $SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom,$EmailTo,$Subject,$body)      
      }
      }
$errorCount = 0
start-sleep -seconds 30
}Until ((get-date).Hour -eq $TimeStop.Hour -and (get.date).Minute -eq $TimeStop.Minute)
$ping = $null
```

Comment: Your email sending block of code is inside the `foreach` loop. Is that intentional?

Comment: if it sends 3 copies, then you're calling `.send()` three times. probably beacuse you've got the send stuff inside your foreach loop.

Comment: well, that was it. i had a brace down on the below the email part, keeping it in the foreach loop. stupid mistake that i couldn't see. Thanks a lot!!